# How can I implement a windowed rolling average with KSQL KTable correctly?

Tags: ksqldb

I am trying to implement a volume rolling average into KSQL.

Kafka currently ingests data from a producer into the topic "KLINES". This data is across multiple markets with a consistent format. I then create a stream from that data like so:

```
CREATE STREAM KLINESTREAM (market VARCHAR, open DOUBLE, high DOUBLE, low DOUBLE, close DOUBLE, volume DOUBLE, start_time BIGINT, close_time BIGINT, event_time BIGINT) \
WITH (VALUE_FORMAT='JSON', KAFKA_TOPIC='KLINES', TIMESTAMP='event_time', KEY='market');
```

I then create a table which calculates the average volume over the last 20 minutes for each market like so:

```
CREATE TABLE AVERAGE_VOLUME_TABLE_BY_MARKET AS \
SELECT CEIL(SUM(volume) / COUNT(*)) AS volume_avg, market FROM KLINESTREAM \
WINDOW HOPPING (SIZE 20 MINUTES, ADVANCE BY 5 SECONDS) \ 
GROUP BY market;
```

```
SELECT * FROM AVERAGE_VOLUME_TABLE_BY_MARKET LIMIT 1;
```

For clarity, produces:

```
1560647412620 | EXAMPLEMARKET : Window{start=1560647410000 end=-} | 44.0 | EXAMPLEMARKET
```

**What I wish to have is a KSQL Table that will represent the current "kline" state of each market while also including that rolling average volume calculated in "AVERAGE_VOLUME_TABLE_BY_MARKET" KTable so I can perform analysis between current volume and the average rolling volume**

I have tried to join like so:

```
SELECT K.market, K.open, K.high, K.low, K.close, K.volume, V.volume_avg \
FROM KLINESTREAM K \
LEFT JOIN AVERAGE_VOLUME_TABLE_BY_MARKET V \
ON K.market = V.market;
```

But obviously this results in an error as the "AVERAGE_VOLUME_TABLE_BY_MARKET" key includes the TimeWindow and also the market.

```
A serializer (key:
    org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.TimeWindowedSerializer) is not compatible to
    the actual key type (key type: java.lang.String). Change the default Serdes in
    StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters.
```

Am I approaching this problem correctly?

What I want to achieve is:

```
Windowed Aggregate KTable + Kline Stream -> 
KTable representing current market state 
including average volume from the KTable
```

which displays the current market state possible in KSQL. Or must I use KStreams or another library to accomplish this?

A great aggregation example is here: https://www.confluent.io/stream-processing-cookbook/ksql-recipes/aggregating-data

Applicable to this example, how would I use the aggregate to compare to fresh data as it arrives in the KSQL Table?

Cheers, James

Comment: Is it acceptable to join the most recent entry in the average table with the stream, or do you need to properly account for late arriving data? What I mean by this is if the "current" average is 10 but the average from the last window (20 min ago) is 5, and I get an event timestamped from 20 minutes ago -  is it acceptable to pair it with the current average?

Comment: My use case would be that any late arriving data would not apply as decisions need to be made in real time.

I have since achieved this in Apache Flink using a low level join. However I'm sure this can also be easily done in Kafka Streams, maybe not KSQL at this stage :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for may be [LATEST_BY_OFFSET](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/aggregate-functions/#latest_by_offset):

```sql
CREATE TABLE AVERAGE_VOLUME_TABLE_BY_MARKET AS
  SELECT 
    market,
    LATEST_BY_OFFSET(volume) AS volume,
    CEIL(SUM(volume) / COUNT(*)) AS volume_avg 
  FROM KLINESTREAM
    WINDOW HOPPING (SIZE 20 MINUTES, ADVANCE BY 5 SECONDS)
  GROUP BY market;
```

Comment: Looks like they rolled out a new update since I asked this question. Thanks.

Comment: James, if you're happy with this answer can you mark your question answered please? Thanks!